# Facebook Api Windows Universal get WebAuthentication result

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, authentication, win-universal-app

I want to get the response of the login dialog, how do I get it? My aim is to ensure that the user granted succesfully the permission and I get the code to exchange it with by an access token:

My Url for GET request:

```
public async void getAccessByLogin()
{
    string request_string = string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&display={1}&response_type={2}&redirect_uri={3}&scope={4}",
    Uri.EscapeDataString(RequestConstants.app_id.ToString()),
    Uri.EscapeDataString("popup"),
    Uri.EscapeDataString("token"),
    Uri.EscapeDataString(WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString()),
    Uri.EscapeDataString("email"));
    Uri request_uri = new Uri(request_string);
    await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, request_uri);
}
```

To login I call this method in the getAccessByLogin method:

```
await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, request_uri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br212068.aspx), you will see that it returns *WebAuthenticationResult*. You can handle it for example like this:

```cs
WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, request_uri);
if (result.ResponseStatus != WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    await new MessageDialog("Problem!").ShowAsync();
else // do something
```